# Array struct toupper for whole string and after space

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, c-strings, toupper

I'm trying to put in upper case a first letter in a name. Something does not work. Also, I want to put whole surname in upper case. Which doesn't work too. Somehow only the first letter(of the above mentioned) get an upper case.

I have this code, and it does not work as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int year_of_birth;
};

void display(struct Student array[],int size);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    struct Student* array = malloc(n*sizeof(array));


    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]*c",array[i].name);
        printf("enter surname: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]*c",array[i].surname);
        printf("enter birth year: ");
        scanf(" %d",&array[i].year_of_birth);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            array[i].surname[j] = toupper(array[i].surname[j]);
            array[i].name[0] = toupper(array[i].name[0]);
            if(isspace(array[i].name[j]))
                array[i].name[j+1] = toupper(array[i].name[j+1]);

        }
    }


    puts("");
    puts("::SHOWING::");

    display(array,n);


    return 0;
}

void display(struct Student array[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("Student info %d: %s %s %d \n",i+1,array[i].name,array[i].surname,array[i].year_of_birth);
    }

}
```

The output:

> enter number: 2
>
> enter name: olivia emma
>
> enter surname: james
>
> enter birth year: 2000
>
> enter name: john noah
>
> enter surname: Smith
>
> enter birth year: 2002
>
> ::SHOWING:: Student info 1: Olivia emma JAmes 2000  Student info 2:
> John noah SMith 2002

Expected output:

> Student info 1: Olivia Emma JAMES 2000  Student info 2: John Noah
> SMITH 2002

Comment: Please show your input, the actual output, and the expected output.

Comment: Your `malloc` call is wrong. You should not allocate for `n` times the size of a `Student *`, what you are doing now. It should be either `n * sizeof(struct Student)` or `n * sizeof *array`.

Comment: Explain what the inner loop with `j` is for. It makes no sense. Maybe you should consider the fact that you don't have a call to `strlen` anywhere.

Comment: Also don't use hacks like `scanf(" %[^\n]*c", ...)`. Use `fgets`, check the return value, error out if the input string is too long. The scanf hack will just happily proceed to overwrite your memory.

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I fixed the malloc, and implemented the strlen for the second loop and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you are allocating a memory of an invalid size

```
struct Student* array = malloc(n*sizeof(array));
```

It seems you mean

```
struct Student* array = malloc(n*sizeof(*array));
```

In these calls of scanf

```
    scanf(" %[^\n]*c",array[i].name);
    printf("enter surname: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]*c",array[i].surname);
```

the conversion specifiers *c are redundant. White space characters will be skipped in any case due to leading spaces in the format strings. So you could write

```
    scanf(" %49[^\n]",array[i].name);
    printf("enter surname: ");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]",array[i].surname);
```

For the data member `surname` you could use a loop as for example

```
   for ( char *p = array[i].surname; *p != '\0'; ++p )
   { 
        *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
   }
```

For the data member name you could use another loop

```
  #include <string.h>

  //...

  for ( char *p = array[i].name; *p != '\0'; p += strspn( p, " \t" ) )
  {
      *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
      p += strcspn( p, " \t" );
  }
```